# Direct Limit in HTop

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I am currently trying to figure out the importance of homotopy direct limits in Top, which are of course different from direct limits in HTop. I have been told that the latter need not even exist, but I have had a hard time finding an example. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you mean colimits? If yes, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10364

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

An explicit example of a diagram without colimit in $\mathsf{hTop}$ is $S^1 \leftarrow S^1 \to D^2$, where $S^1 \to S^1$ is $z \mapsto z^2$ and $S^1 \to D^2$ is the inclusion. You can find a proof [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10364/categorical-homotopy-colimits).